# Behavior of DocManager.DavProtocolEditDocument with cookie authentication

Tags: webdav, ithit-webdav-server, ithit-ajax-file-browser

I am attempting to open a word document on the WebDav server using cookie authentication. When I use the `EditDocument()` method with a url of `<webdavServer>/info/about/file.docx`, the browser asks to open Microsoft Word and then sends two requests, one has the path with the file removed and one has the full path. This seems to work.

However, when I change to using `DavProtocolEditDocument()`, the browser wants to open the IT Hit Edit Document Opener 3 app. After a couple of "Allow" screens, my webdav server gets a series of requests with either a blank path or nothing but "/". The cookie I request (or all cookies, if I don't name one) are in the request headers, but the server is behaving weird.

So, what am I supposed to be doing in this scenario? Do I have to manually check for a cookie and send something back? What do I send back in this case? Where is the path going and why don't I have access to it anymore?

Answer (score 0):

The WebDAV client application, in your case MS Mini-redirector driver, which works behind the scenes, submits OPTIONS and PROPFIND WebDAV requests to the root or your WebDAV server as well as to each folder in file path. This is a normal behavior for MS Office and MS Mini-redirector.

You WebDAV server must process these WebDAV requests and provide a valid WebDAV response. You can capture requests using Fiddler tool, WireShark or any other HTTP debugging proxy and see if they were processed successfully.

What you will do with a cookie depend on your authentication implementation. If you have added WebDAV to ASP.NET Application using '[Add WebDAV Server Implementation](https://www.webdavsystem.com/server/documentation/vs_wizards/)' wizard in Visual Studio it will be processed by ASP.NET authentication modules and the either excepted or rejected.